# Ubuntu vs. Yellow Dog for ps3

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ps3

I've heard that Yellow Dog is the way to go as far as linux distros for the PS3 but apparently ubuntu has a alternate distro now and I was wondering if anyone had any experience with either?

I want to use ubuntu because that is what I'm used to but I wondering if Yellow Dog takes advantage of the specialized hardware more? If I was going to do it, I would use it for gaming (emulation) and some development like running services or something.

Comment: I wonder why this question is migrated to Super User, SU is NOT about consoles!

Comment: SU is not about things that are `purely videogame or console related`. This isn't about that, it's about linux. If it were linux on a PC, it wouldn't be closed, just because the PS3's primary purpose it gaming does not mean that's all it can be used for.

Comment: Its relevant here because 1) PS3 is effectively a specialised computer that can run general OSs such as Ubuntu; I didn't think there was a rigid definition on SU of what a PC has to be, diverse computing platforms, apart from the ordinary x86 archirecture should be supported on SU 2) The subject is about Ubuntu which is a subject relevant to SU 3) It is not talking about games themselves - that would warrant discussion elsewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd actually say Ubuntu probably has a slight upper hand. It all depends on what you want to use and what you're comfortable with though.

Yellow Dog is rpm based and is a fork of CentOS (5.2 if I remember correctly). It will use older software but it will also be very stable because of this.

Ubuntu on the other hand is deb based and **very frequently updated**. A ton of software is available for it and you'll feel more comfortable with it. One downside is that the installer can't run in Live mode in 480i or 480p, but there's a text based installer to get around that.

Choose what's best for you, which sounds like Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks. I was asking a buddy about YD and he also mentioned RPMs... yuck! I think I will go with Ubuntu.

Comment: +1 for ubuntu. i found that ps3linux community generally prefers ubuntu, so it should be easier to find help on irc, etc. also running ubuntu myself. can't say anything about YD (never tried it).